# visual studio gives me an error about an old DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I've upgraded an old .net1 project to vs2010. Everything works, except that designer gives me an error when opening some forms that use components from a referenced DLL.

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.YYY, Version=1.0.2363.24558, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att hitta filen.

I've recompiled the DLL and removed all references to the old one, then added references to the new one but still Deisgner keeps nagging about this specific non-existent version?
As said.. everything works when running the application, but the Designer seems to hate it.

Anyone with a clue? I'm not much of a .net hacker, I confess..

EDIT:
The application works, as said. If I choose "ignore & continue" the form shows up but without my Usercontrol. If I open the specific Usercontrol, it does show up however.
But why won't it show up in the form, and how come that it works smooth but the designer refuses to show it since it has this weird idea that somewhere in my solution it's referencing that old assembly.. which apparantly doesn't exist???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it turned out there were a reference for another old DLL file that in turn were built using the troublesome DLL version.
An upgrade of that project and recompiling with the new DLL solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Find in Solution <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> where this line is being used... probably there's some place that is still referencing the old DLL.

Look for this string: `1.0.2363.24558`

Other thing you can try is: right click your project in `Solution Explorer` and select `Unload Project` (I'm using VS 11 Beta here). Then right click it again and select `Edit 'ProjectName'.csproj`. Then look there to see if there's a reference for this assembly version...

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried that but without any luck. I'm kind of confused :S

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I tried that but all the references to the DLL are mentioning the correct version. It really puzzles me, this specific string doesn't exist anywhere in my solution when I search for it :(